# Why won't cygwin read the .ssh/config file in my home directory?

Tags: windows, windows-7, ssh, cygwin

I am using cygwin and I am trying to set up an .ssh/config file. Cygwin's folder is in my C: drive. My Home directory is C:\Users\USER. I have noticed that when I edit C:\Users\USER.ssh\config, cygwin does not even notice it (even though it notices the other files I have in my USER folder, i.e. .bashrc). But it does notice the config file if I put it in C:\cygwin64\home\USER.ssh\config.

Is there a way to get cygwin to read the .ssh folder in my USER home directory instead?

Comment: Are you sure you have package openssh installed?
Perhabs, you are using windows ssh.exe

Comment: modern answer: `db_home: /%H` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573763/i-am-unable-to-find-the-etc-passwd-file-in-cygwin for more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your home directory setup in /etc/passwd matches /home/  Often it is not set at all (second to last field in the ':' delimited line.  Then you'll need to restart your cygwin session (exit the terminal, and restart)

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the greatest solution but it works:

```
ln -s /cygdrive/c/Users/username/.ssh /home/username/.ssh
```

If /home/username/.ssh already exists, perhaps rename it to .ssh_original or move the files into the other .ssh folder.